# Ninject 101 for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am new to Ninject and trying to figure out the implementation.  I am searching and reading, can anyone point me to some good examples and documentation specific to Ninject and MVC.

I can get the basics working, I am struggling with Bindings that have dependencies.  For example, I have the following classes:

```
  public class ScheduleService : IScheduleService
    {
        private IValidationDictionary validationDictionary;
        public ScheduleService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary)
         {
             this.validationDictionary = validationDictionary;
         }
    }
```

That depends on:

```
public class ModelStateWrapper : IValidationDictionary
    {
        private ModelStateDictionary _modelState;

        public ModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            _modelState = modelState;
        }
```

That I want to create bindings for:

```
 Bind<IValidationDictionary>()
                    .To<ModelStateWrapper>();

                Bind<IScheduleService>()
                    .To<ScheduleService>();
```

How do set up the bindings so my controller can use ScheduleService?  How does it get the ModelState?

Clarification:
I want to inject this into the the schedule service class, which handles the business logic.  I have Ninject working, just not sure how to handle dependencies.  Below is my controller code.

```
public class ScheduleController : ActivityController
{
    private IScheduleService scheduleService;


    public ScheduleController(IScheduleService scheduleService)
    {
        this.scheduleService = new ScheduleService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState));
    }
```

Thanks for your patience, I may not be asking the right question.  It builds but when I run it, I get:

Error activating IValidationDictionary
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
 3) Injection of dependency IValidationDictionary into parameter validationDictionary of constructor of type ScheduleService
 2) Injection of dependency IScheduleService into parameter scheduleService of constructor of type ScheduleController
 1) Request for ScheduleController

Suggestions:
 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IValidationDictionary.
 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
 4) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

Comment: I would probably rethink this solution. ModelState is something contextual to a specific action and therefore can't be injected at a global level.

Comment: This may also be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127184/ninject-error-he-icontrollerfactory-ninject-web-mvc-ninjectcontrollerfactory-d/4127715#4127715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing you might consider is injecting a factory to produce the IValidationDictionary.  for example, your controller constructor would take a IValidationFactory, and IValidationFactory has one method: GetValidation(ModelStateDictionary modelState) and your default implementation returns your ModelStateWrapper.  this allows you full IoC and you can inject your own stubs for unit testing.

if there is only one or two methods on IValidationDictionary, you could also just pass ModelState into the methods being called, instead of trying to inject it into the constructor.

Comment: Could you show some code of this. I can't figure out to do this(your first part not passing it in by method)

Comment: after re-reading the original question and thinking about it more, I think my answer is incorrect, or invalid.  he's asking for the IScheduleService to be injected with the ModelStateWrapper, not the controller.  because the controller has no control over the creation of the schedule service, there's no way to get it the ModelState.  if I had to do this in my application, I would pass in the ModelStateWrapper as an IValidationDictionary argument to the method being called on IScheduleService.

Comment: Can you elaborate your last line?

Comment: `scheduleService.Validate( new ModelStateWrapper( ModelState ) );`

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something along the lines of:

**Setting up Ninject2**

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //Here goes routing setup
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return new StandardKernel(new ServiceModule());
    }
}

internal class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IValidationDictionary>().To<ModelStateWrapper>();
        Bind<IScheduleService>().To<ScheduleService>();
    }
}
```

**Injecting into Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IValidationDictionary _validationDictionary;
    private readonly IScheduleService _scheduleService;

    public HomeController(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary, IScheduleService scheduleService)
    {
        _validationDictionary = validationDictionary;
        _scheduleService = scheduleService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this. The modelstate is something that is set by the controller when it is initialized. I don't know Ninject, but you should be able to do a contextual resolving of your service and pass it the current modelstate. This isn't really a nice solution and I wouldn't recommend it.

Basically your problem here is that Ninject doesn't know how to resolve ModelStateDictionary as you haven't told it how. If the dependency to you modelstatewrapper class was something else that isn't contextual then you would just need to set that up in Ninject to make it work.